# Exporting Airflow connections from the CLI formatting

Tags: connection, command-line-interface, airflow

I'm trying to set up a `connection.json` file in my local directory, so every time I spin up airflow on my docker container, it loads these connections through `entrypoint.sh`, therefore mitigating me having to establish connections via UI or programmatically in DAG.

As per the airflow [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html#creating-a-connection-from-the-cli), this is the proper format.

```
{
  "airflow_db": {
    "conn_type": "mysql",
    "host": "mysql",
    "login": "root",
    "password": "plainpassword",
    "schema": "airflow",
    "port": null,
    "extra": null
  },
  "druid_broker_default": {
    "conn_type": "druid",
    "host": "druid-broker",
    "login": null,
    "password": null,
    "schema": null,
    "port": 8082,
    "extra": "{\"endpoint\": \"druid/v2/sql\"}"
  }
}
```

Is this default format for every conn type?

For example, I'm trying to set up an s3 connection, and a google cloud connection. Here are the parameters on the UI:

[image]

So would I set up this connection in the json like

```
{
  "google_cloud_default": {
    "conn_type": "google_cloud_platform",
    "project_id": "sample-proj-id123",
    "keyfile_path": null,
    "keyfile_json": {sample_json},
    "scopes": "sample_scope",
    "number_of_retries": 5,
  }
```

or like the format pertaining to the airflow docs, however I'd just nullify unnecessary values, and add in data like proj_id, key_file_json, scopes in the extra field?

Hope this makes sense?